# Proof that the intersection of two subgroups is the identity

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

Suppose the group $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ of order $8$ and a subgroup $K$ of order $15$. Prove that $H\cap K=\{e\}$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$.

$\underline{Progress:}$  Clearly $e\in H\cap K$ as $H,K$ are subgroups and so must contain the identity. However I don't see how to prove no other elements can be in their intersection. An idea would be to assume there is some $a\ne e$ such that $a\in H\cap K$, meaning $a\in H, a\in K$. Hence $a^{-1}\in H\cap K$. But I can't see how to go any further here.

Comment: What are the possible orders of an element in $H$?  What about $K$?

Comment: @lulu Ah I see! So we have that the gcd is 1 so the only element that can be in both is the identity

Comment: @Randall this is great, thanks!

Comment: $H, K\le G \implies H\cap K \le G$

And, $H\cap K \subseteq H, K$

$\implies H\cap K \le H,K$

Then by Lagrange's theorem,$| H\cap K | \text {divides } |H| \text { and } |K|.$

$\implies |H\cap K | $ is common divisor of $ 8 $ and $15$.

And, only choice is $1$.

Hence, $H\cap K =\{e_G\}$